# Writing actual packet data, pcap

Tags: c++, wireshark, packet, dump, libpcap

I'm writing a program that should convert strongSwan log to WireShark packets. So, for instance, we have a sequence like this one in a text file.

```
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] sending cert request for "C=RU, ST=NW, O=Company, CN=StronSwanSERV"
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] shared Diffie Hellman secret => 128 bytes @ 0x7f36e8001ed0
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 0: 23 D9 25 9F F1 78 9F C4 83 89 2F 06 E3 DB C2 69 #.%..x..../....i
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 16: 24 06 49 01 75 2E 6A 4F AF E6 07 9C F9 77 07 A1 $.I.u.jO.....w..
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 32: 02 D8 52 0C F0 27 10 14 19 69 B8 B7 CB 0F 41 40 ..R..'...i....A@
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 48: 72 AA 50 8C 90 FF 4D C8 66 88 6C F8 44 B3 2E A2 r.P...M.f.l.D...
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 64: 62 F4 C8 4B 31 3C A9 DF DE C8 DF 85 6D 3E E7 56 b..K1<......m>.V
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 80: 9D 32 6B 29 C9 7E 9F 41 9C C2 EB D8 8D 3F 51 68 .2k).~.A.....?Qh
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 96: 75 74 3A 96 D6 09 B6 34 38 D8 28 5E 6F 7D 20 44 ut:....48.(^o} D
Feb 14 14:53:22 dubu12 charon: 13[IKE] 112: E3 3F 72 1E DD A5 73 B0 CC E0 92 8C 7A 54 3B 34 .?r...s.....zT;4
```

I have my own class that performs all the actions via Libpcap.

```
int TgrReader::dump(std::deque<TgrPacket> deqTgrPacket, char* fileName)
{
  pcap_t* pHandle = pcap_open_dead(DLT_RAW, 65535);
  pcap_dumper_t* pDumper = pcap_dump_open(pHandle, fileName);
  std::deque<TgrPacket>::iterator iter=deqTgrPacket.begin();
  while(iter != deqTgrPacket.end())
  {
    pcap_dump(reinterpret_cast<u_char*>(pDumper), &(iter->header), reinterpret_cast<u_char*>(iter->data.toLocal8Bit().data()));
    iter++;
  }
  pcap_dump_close(pDumper);
  pcap_close(pHandle);
  return 0;
}
```

So, we have that packet. We have the header for packet made, data (strings from 0: to 112:) is being stored in char* variable. I'm trying to dump a packet like this, but it messes up positions somehow

.[image]
I tried to google a proper way of dumping in a situation like this, but can't seem to find a solution. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

## ============================================

UPD:
The deque with data contains elements of this:

```
struct TgrPacket
{
  pcap_pkthdr header;
  QString data;
  TgrPacket(pcap_pkthdr pHeader, QString pData);
};
```

So the data is stored in a single QString. While scanning the text file, I'm looking for the first string of data (that looks like "... 0: 23 D9 25...") and cut everything from ": " and append it to the QString data. Then I get data from next strings until I reach the last line of this packet, then I start looking for new packets again. After I finished appending my QString, I get the time of the packet, convert it to time_val and create a structure with time_val field and QString with data.
The function is like this if you want to have a look:

```
std::deque<TgrPacket> TgrReader::readFile(std::deque<TgrPacket>& deqTgrPacket)
{
    //1) read to "dataString"
    //2) parse it
    //3) loop add data from "dataString" to "qDataString" if data was found
    //4) eject time from "dataString" and add it to "vTm", which is struct tm type
    //5) create packet and add to deque
    char* dataString = new char [ 255 ];
    char* dataBlock = new char [40];
    QString* qTimeString = new QString;
    QString* qTempDataString = new QString;
    time_t vTime_t = 0;
    struct tm* vTm = new tm;
    while(!feof(srcFile))
    {
        fgets(dataString, 65535, srcFile);
        switch(parse(dataString, stringState))
        {
        case BLANK: //skip blank lines
            stringState = BLANK;
            break;
        case LINE: //read data lines until last one is read
            stringState = LINE;
            qTimeString = new QString;            
            qTempDataString = new QString;
            vTime_t = 0;
            vTm = new tm;
            while(stringState != END && !feof(srcFile))
            {
                sscanf(dataString, "%*s %*s %*s %s", dataBlock);
                for(int j = 39 + strlen(dataBlock); j < strlen(dataString) - 17; j++)
                {
                    qTempDataString->append(dataString[j]);
                }
                fgets(dataString, 65535, srcFile);                
                qTimeString->append(dataString);
                stringState = parse(dataString, stringState);
            }
            stringState = END;
            qTimeString->truncate(15);
            vTm->tm_year = 114;
            strptime(qTimeString->toLatin1().data(),"%h  %d %H:%M:%S",vTm);
            vTime_t = mktime(vTm);
            deqTgrPacket.push_back(createPacket(&vTime_t, qTempDataString, qTempDataString->length()));
            break;
        }
    }
    return deqTgrPacket;
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably how you *read* the source log file and how you store your data in the structure(s) you have. Please show the involved structures and how you read/parse the actual data from the log file.

Comment: Added some more info for you, hope this will help us to find a solution

Comment: To start with, you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code: You allocate 255 characters for `dataString` but then allow up to 65535 bytes to be read into it. Also you should never to `while (!feof(...))`, as the EOF flag is not set until after you try to read from beyond the file. In this case do `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`. And why are you using C file I/O instead of C++ streams? And why pointers for the `QString` objects (which you allocate twice and never free). And you never free the `vTm` object either (no pointer needed here too).

Comment: Even if some functions require a pointer, you don't actually have to use pointers and `new`. Take for example your `mktime` call, it wants you to provide a pointer to a `struct tm`, so you make a pointer and allocate memory for it. Instead you can just declare a non-pointer variable and use the address-of operator to make a pointer of it, like `tm vTm; ...; vTime_t = mktime(&vTm);` No pointer, no allocation, no memory leak.

Comment: Thx for all the advises, I'll work on it in the future for sure. But still, the main problem at the moment is incorrert data writing. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: I assume it's the `createPacket` function which does the actual translation of the data? Can you please show that too?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/pHtgmDrV  You probably won't like it as well, lol, but it does work. I checked via debugger, the string passes correctly, all the data ends up in TgrPacket without any losses

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know PCAP really, I will make an educated guess: The `pcap_dump` function expects the data (passed as the last argument) to be the actual *binary* data of the packet. Since you read and stored the data as a string then `pcap_dump` will dump the ASCII values.

You should probably parse the data into bytes of binary data instead of as a string. Using the standard library (as I don't know Qt well enough) you could probably do something like this:

```
std::istringstream istr(qTempDataString->toStdString());
std::string value;
std::string data;
while (istr >> value)
    data += static_cast<char>(std::stoi(value, nullptr, 16));

*qTempDataString = QString::fromStdString(data);
```

The important bits here are the `istr >> value` which extracts a whitespace delimited "word" from the stream and puts it into the string `value`, and `std::stoi(value, nullptr, 16)` which takes the string and converts it to a number (the `16` is the base, which is hexadecimal).

Comment: Thx a lot, it looks like the solution. The last thing that isn't working is that when I apply this algorithm it works OK for numbers like 17, 20, 33 etc (without letters), but when it tries to convert BB, DC and B9 it gives ef, bf and bd respectively. Any idea about that?

Comment: @LeonidBor If the base is set to 16, then it should work for all hexadecimal numbers (which includes the letters).